# Retrieve array function not working

Tags: arrays, swift, nscoding

I created two functions called save array and retrieve array and their job is to save and retrieve an array from the phone. My problem is that they are not working. These are the two functions.

```
func SaveArray (array: [IOU],fileID: String){
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(array, toFile: fileID)
}
func RetrieveArray (fileID: String, var array: [IOU]) -> [IOU]{
    if let arraytoRetrieve = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileID) as? [IOU]{
        array = arraytoRetrieve
    }
    return array
}
```

IOU is a class I have defined like this:

```
class IOU : NSObject, NSCoding {

var Amount : Double
var Payer : String
var Description : String



init (amount: Double, payer: String, description: String){
    self.Amount = amount
    self.Payer = payer
    self.Description = description

    super.init()

}

required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
    let amount = decoder.decodeDoubleForKey("amount")
    let payer = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("payer") as! String
    let description = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("description") as! String
    self.init(amount: amount,payer: payer,description: description)
}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeDouble(self.Amount, forKey: "amount")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.Payer, forKey: "payer")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.Description, forKey: "description")
}


}
```

And I implemented my retrieve function in the viewWillAppear method like this:

```
Debts = RetrieveArray("Debts", array: Debts)
```

But for some unknown reason, when I run a playground test like the one below, it works just fine:

```
var IOUArray : [IOU] = [IOU]()


var example = IOU(amount: 70, payer: "Jackson", description: "Because")
IOUArray.append(example)


func SaveArray (array: [IOU],fileID: String){
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(array, toFile: fileID)
}
func RetrieveArray (fileID: String) -> [IOU]{
    let IOUA = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fileID) as! [IOU]
    return IOUA
}

SaveArray(IOUArray, fileID: "IOUArray")
RetrieveArray("IOUArray")
print(RetrieveArray("IOUArray")[0].Amount)
```

Comment: No offense, but your code is very hard to read. According Apple's naming guidelines variables and methods are supposed to start with a lowercase letter. Even the syntax highlighter of SO is confused.

Comment: None taken. I am well aware my code is difficult to read, it's just a habit. HoweverI don't see how the syntax highlighter is confused @vadian

Comment: Just kidding, I mean that functions like `encodeWithCoder` or variables like `example` are not highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the parameter `toFile` in the method `archiveRootObject` and the parameter in `unarchiveObjectWithFile` must be a valid file path..

`archiveRootObject` returns `true` if the operation was successful, otherwise `false`

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm just wondering how my playground operation worked just fine and why it does not need a file path?