# Valid file path for archiverootobject and unarchiverootobject

Tags: ios, swift, save, nskeyedarchiver

I am making an iPhone app and in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627674/retrieve-array-function-not-working) I was told that I needed a valid file path for archiverootobject and unarchiverootobject but I don't know how to make one. So what is a valid file path to save arrays of custom classes?

Follow up question: On the linked question I have set up my methods to use invalid  saves but it still works would anyone know why?

Comment: You can save it to a subdirectory folder named with your bundleID inside the application support folder or you can also save it to the preferences folder located inside the library directory

Comment: How would I do that @Leo Dabus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save it to a subdirectory folder named with your bundleID inside the application support folder or you can also save it to the preferences folder located inside the library directory:

```
let preferencesDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Preferences", isDirectory: true)
let fileURL = preferencesDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.plist")
print(fileURL.path)   // "/var/folders/.../Library/Preferences/fileName.plist
```

Comment: @needshelp I believe in your case you probably need a file name for each array. You would need to provide some more info otherwise I would be guessing. As vadian already mentioned you need to proper format your code, it is very hard to read it.

Comment: So can I name filename.plist whatever I want or does it need to match another file name?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want, just keep the plist extension.