# Making a Struct with a Float encodable with Swift 4

Tags: swift, struct, codable

I've got a struct that contains descriptions of People (height, age, gender). Age is a Float because it could be counted in months for infants (ie: 1.083 years is 13 months).

I'm trying to save an array of these People to User Defaults, but can't figure out how to make the class codable. In the class is Strings, one Float, and a Dictionary [String:String].

Suggestions?

Struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var gender: String
    var age: Float
    var profilePictures: [String: String]

    init(name: String,
         gender: String,
         age: Float,
         profilePictures: [String: String])

    {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.profilePictures = profilePictures
    }
}
```

Class where I try to save the results to User Defaults:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(self.people, forKey: "people") // Where self.people is an array of Person objects
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Is its compile error? Runtime error?

Comment: Added the error - thanks

Comment: @devpreneur UserDefaults it is not meant to save App data. Better to save your app data to a regular json file. Check this answer for a better location to save App data which is just available to your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701630/valid-file-path-for-archiverootobject-and-unarchiverootobject/34701970#34701970

Comment: I suggest also you take a look at File System Basics documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Thanks, will go read both of those #learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to pass an array of person type to the json decoder when decoding your data. I suggest instead of saving it into UserDefaults it would be better to write the data to a json file:

```
let person = Person(name: "devpreneur", gender: "male", age: 99, profilePictures: ["SO profile picture": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz3pC.jpg"])
let people = [person]
do{
    let peopleData = try JSONEncoder().encode(people)
    // saving your people data
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let jsonURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("people.json")
    try peopleData.write(to: jsonURL, options: .atomic)

    // loading and decoding the json data
    let loadedData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL)
    let decodedPeople = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: loadedData)
    for person in decodedPeople {
        print(person.name)
        print(person.gender)
        print(person.age)
        print(person.profilePictures)
    }
} catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Got it writing and reading the local copy. Thanks a lot for the quick & detailed response.