# Set array of objects in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swifty-json, userdefaults

how to set and later get array of json objects in `UserDefaults`?

My application crashes when i try to set it as follow:

```
import SwiftyJSON
var finalArray = [JSON]()

UserDefaults.standard.set(finalArray, forKey: "attemptedArray")
```

my data looks like:

```
[{
  "marked" : 3,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 3,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 219,
  "answer" : 32931,
  "time" : 15,
  "score" : 5,
  "chapter" : 26
}, {
  "marked" : 4,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 4,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 550,
  "answer" : 34256,
  "time" : 23,
  "score" : 10,
  "chapter" : 26
}, {
  "marked" : 1,
  "attempted" : true,
  "correct" : 1,
  "subject" : 1,
  "status" : true,
  "question" : 566,
  "answer" : 34317,
  "time" : 33,
  "score" : 14,
  "chapter" : 26
}]
```

Comment: "My application crashes" And what's the error message? `JSON` doesn't seem to be NSCoding compliant and you can't save anything you want into `UserDefaults` (you need to transform it into allowed types). Check the doc of it.

Comment: it cant save objects of user created classes... You are saving objects of 'JSON', convert it into dictionary, then you can save

Comment: You have variable named `finalArr` but you are setting `finalArray `. Please use the proper variable.

Comment: You could maybe convert to `[[String : Any]]`?

Comment: This is abusing user defaults. Please don't abuse user defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserDefaults` can't save SwiftyJSON's `JSON` type. You have to save some type which they supports, in this case, you're looking for `Data`.

Anyway, for saving `Data` to `UserDefaults` aren’t the best and you should save your `Data` to file somewhere else. To achieve this, you can use `FileManager`.

---

So, create custom model for your data instead of using `JSON` and adopt `Codable` to your custom model

```
struct Model: Codable {
    var marked, correct, subject, question, answer, time, score, chapter: Int
    var attempted, status: Bool
}
```

Then you should use this `Model` as type of element inside your array (note that then you’ll need to decode your response from `Data` using `JSONDecoder` (see below))

```
var finalArray = [Model]()
```

then you can use `JSONEncoder` for encoding your array of models to `Data` which you can write to some file

```
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(finalArray)
    let preferencesDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Preferences", isDirectory: true)
    let fileURL = preferencesDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.json")
    try encoded.write(to: fileURL)
} catch { print(error) }
```

and `JSONDecoder` for decoding `Data` from saved file

```
do {
    let preferencesDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("Preferences", isDirectory: true)
    let fileURL = preferencesDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.json")

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: The Codable implementation is fine. What it is not is saving the data to UserDefaults. It is mean for storing only the interface state of the App. It is not meant for storing general app data. You can write the data to disk into a separate file `.json` (which is just a simple text file properly formatted) to the same directory  UserDefaults uses to store its preferences file `Library/Preferences` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701970/2303865

Comment: Related https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
            try let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: finalArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "attemptedArray")
        }catch{
            print("Print exception here")
        }
```

Read:- [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @DeepakVerma, See updated answer. You need to use the latest syntax according to iOS 12

Answer (score 0):

Saving a lot of data in the NSuser defaults isn’t recommended for some reasons:

1. If you will delete some of the cells of the array you will need to delete them from the nsuser defaults. It will be easy only if you save them as an 
   array and not as individuals.
2. If you choose to save them as array every time you will delete or add one item you will need to save all of them. It can take slot of time if the array is big
3. Anyone can access the NSuser defaults. So it isn’t safe

Anyway I really recommend using core data. It saves you all the troubles I mentioned.