# How to save a dictionary to a file in the User/Documents folder?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to save a dictionary structure as a file in the user's Documents folder.

I'm having problems finding the way to specify the path or url for the file location.

The following code works to save a dictionary to a file but is there a way to specify that it be saved in the user's Documents folder rather than the default which is embedded deep in the user/Library/Containers/com...etc.?

```
let docsBaseURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let customPlistURL = docsBaseURL.appendingPathComponent("ItemList.plist")
NSDictionary(dictionary: myDictionary).write(to: customPlistURL, atomically: true)
```

Comment: Not if the app is sandboxed. And don't use *objective-c-ish* `NSDictionary` to write plists. There is `PropertyListSerialization`.

Comment: @vadian if OP prompts the user a `NSSavePanel` for him to choose the destination directory it is OK.

Comment: See [Powerbox and File System Access Outside of Your Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW17).

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn’t be inclined to save a file with a generic `plist` extension in the main `Documents` folder. IMHO, the files that you should be real user “documents” with extensions that are associated with your app (generally, uniquely so). A user should be able to go to their documents folder, find some file/document, and double tap on it to open it in the app. The question here is whether this file you want to save is a “document” from the user’s perspective, or whether it’s just something the app wants to save and manage for its own purposes.

Comment: macOS Standard Directories: Where Files Reside  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701970/2303865

Comment: Must get used to 'return' sends comment . It is osx so I believe it doesn't  need to be sandboxed & I don't think it is. Prompting with NSSavePanel seems a good idea, tx. @Rob, it is a document the program produces and is only of use to the program. The user may, however, decide to trash some of the models produced which is easier by simply deleting them than deleting via the program. I guess that I can give it whatever extension I like then and make it program specific. I was following examples & procedures I have found but agree something other than plist would be better.

Comment: First, I would always recommend sandboxing. Second, IMHO, if this isn’t a “user document”, then it not only doesn’t belong in the main `Documents` folder, but I don’t even think that the container’s `Documents` folder makes sense, either. I’d put it in the “Application Support” folder. See [The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1).

Comment: Actually 'Application Support' was my first thought but I didn't know how to put it there. I take your point about sandboxing and there's no reason for it not to be so I will check that. Tx for the link. Swift, xcode, osx, feels like fairy footsteps up a mountain 