# UIFIlesharingEnabled exposes my private files

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, file-sharing

I enabled `UIFilesharingEnabled` option in my app set to true but this was exposes my documents file and my sqlite.db file also.

Then how can restrict on to display/access my database files to user or other apps?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Library Directory section [Apple File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1). There you can find all information regarding where to write your app files:

> **Library**
>
> This is the top-level directory for any files that are not user data
> files. You typically put files in one of several standard
> subdirectories. iOS apps commonly use the Application Support and
> Caches subdirectories; however, you can create custom subdirectories.
> **Use the Library subdirectories for any files you don’t want exposed to
> the user**. Your app should not use these directories for user data
> files. The contents of the Library directory (with the exception of
> the Caches subdirectory) are backed up by iTunes and iCloud. For
> additional information about the Library directory and its commonly
> used subdirectories, see The Library Directory Stores App-Specific
> Files.

You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701970/2303865) how to access the Library directory in your App Bundle

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved by using libraryDirectory.

```swift
private static var __once: NSString = {
    let documentFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .libraryDirectory, 
        .userDomainMask, 
        true)[0] as String
    let databaseFile = "DATABASE_FILE_NAME" 
    return "\(documentFolderPath)\(databaseFile)" as NSString
}()
```