# Marker overlays must be png, jpg, or webp while using MapboxStatic api

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, overlay, mapbox-static-maps

This is how I create markers and add it to array of overlays:

```
let text = "1"
let url = URL(string: "http://texttopng.azurewebsites.net/Home/TextToPng?text=\(text)")!
let marker = CustomMarker(coordinate: label.location.coordinate, url: url)
```

but when I try to do a snapshot:

```
_ = Snapshot(options: options, accessToken: nil).image { image, error in
    //error: Error Domain=MBStaticErrorDomain Code=-1 "Marker overlays must be png, jpg, or webp" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Marker overlays must be png, jpg, or webp}
}
```

Why it happens like this?

This is what I have tried:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "icon-card")!
let png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
let newurl = png.write(withName: "\(text).png")
let marker = CustomMarker(coordinate: label.location.coordinate, url: newurl)

extension Data {
func write(withName name: String) -> URL {

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(name)

    try! write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)

    return url
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to download, save it locally and use the fileURL

Comment: Good idea. I will try it...

Comment: It looks like it cannot be local file url;(

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what you have tried?

Comment: I just editet. As a result I get error `Custom image not found`.

Comment: Try using a permanent URL. Temporary files will be removed as soon as your method which created them finishes.

Comment: Permanent URL? How can I do that?

Comment: You can save it to your application support directory or to the documents directory and delete once you finish. You can also use a temporary URL as long as the file exist (inside your method which created the temporary file)

Comment: Could you share your answer with example?;) I am gonna vote it up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701630/valid-file-path-for-archiverootobject-and-unarchiverootobject/34701970 sure but I don't think it is needed. Try the same approach you used above but use another directory

Comment: The same result. `Custom image not found`.

Comment: Doesn’t make sense. Why would it require a resource on the web?

Comment: I dont know, but it works like this... I will share some docs about that function

Comment: Can you show how you are downloading it? Are you using a completion handler?

Comment: I updated the question. I think that library does it for me.

Comment: Try it first with an image url located in your bundle. If it doesn’t work let me know

Comment: Doesnt work. I have added url by `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a", withExtension: "png")!`. The same error: `Custom image not found`. But url for resource exists. The library needs to have server url, not local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share my code and it works without any issues:

```
let text = "Hello"
let urlWithText = URL(string: "http://texttopng.azurewebsites.net/Home/TextToPng?text=\(text)")!
let marker = CustomMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.705912, longitude: 23.840836), url: urlWithText)

let camera = SnapshotCamera(
    lookingAtCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.705912, longitude: 23.840836),
    zoomLevel: 12)
let options = SnapshotOptions(
    styleURL: URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9")!,
    camera: camera,
    size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 200))
options.overlays = [marker]

_ = Snapshot(options: options, accessToken: nil).image { image, error in
    _ = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.write(withName: "my_snapshot.jpg")
}
```

I used your `extension` for `Data` for saving of `jpg` file

```
extension Data {
    func write(withName name: String) -> URL {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(name)
        print(url.path)
        try! write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)
        return url
    }
}
```

and as result I have a shapshot like this:
[image]
I guess you can try use my code or part of it and check with your environment. I use `MapboxStatic.swift (0.11.0)` Mapbox pod

Comment: Yes, indeed it started working today;) I do not know why it works right now;) But thank you for your reply. I am gonna ppreciate that.