# How to get the url for a video saved in temporary directory

Tags: ios, swift, file-management

I need to save a video file to a temp directory and save the reference to it URL. Currently I have tried using fileManager to create a temp directory and then createFile(atPath: tempDirString, contents: vidData, attributes: nil). But I dont/am not able to save the full reference to the file.

What I have tried:

```swift
PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: (cell?.assetPH)!, options: nil) { (avAsset, _, _) in
    if let avAsset = avAsset {
        print(avAsset, " the avasset?")
        // vidAVAsset = avAsset

        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
        print(avPlayer, "<-- good?")

        let finalURL = self.urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer(player: avPlayer)
        print(finalURL, "<-- finalURL YEAH EYAHY YEAH?!?!?")
        // newUserTakenVideo.videoURL = finalURL

        let url = self.addVidToTempURL(vidURL: finalURL!)
        newUserTakenVideo.videoURL = url
        // let newUserTakenVideo = SelectedMedia(videoURL: finalURL, phAsset: (cell?.assetPH)!, thumbnailImg: (cell?.imageView.image)!, uniqueCellID: indexPath)
        // GlobalSharedData.shared.arrayOfCurrentCreateMedia.append(newUserTakenVideo)
    } else {
        print("did noot work")
    }
}
```

This is the function called:

```swift
func addVidToTempURL(vidURL: URL) -> URL? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let tempDir = fileManager.temporaryDirectory
    let tempDirString = tempDir.path
    do {
        print( "tempDir: \(tempDir)" )
        print( "tempDirString: \(tempDirString)" )
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString ) {
            print( "tempDir exists" )
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory( at: tempDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil )
                print( "tempDir created" )
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString ) {
                    print( "tempDir exists" )
                    let vidData = try Data(contentsOf: vidURL)
                    fileManager.createFile(atPath: tempDirString, contents: vidData, attributes: nil)
                    print(tempDirString, " the stringfsdsda")
                    // fileManager.urls(for: fileManager.temporaryDirectory, in: fileManager.)
                    let url = URL(string: tempDirString)
                    return url
                } else {
                    print( "tempDir STILL DOES NOT exist" )
                    return nil
                }
            } catch {
                print( "tempDir NOT created" )
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            print( "tempDir DOES NOT exist" )
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory( at: tempDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil )
                print( "tempDir created" )
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString ) {
                    print( "tempDir exists" )
                    let vidData = try Data(contentsOf: vidURL)
                    fileManager.createFile(atPath: tempDirString, contents: vidData, attributes: nil)
                    print(tempDirString, " the fsdfdsdfsdfsfsd")
                    let url = URL(string: tempDirString)
                    return url
                } else {
                    print( "tempDir STILL DOES NOT exist" )
                    return nil
                }
            } catch {
                print( "tempDir NOT created" )
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I get a URL reference to this files location?**

I appreciate any help and can add more information if needed. Thanks, me

Comment: As the name says it is temporary so as soon as your method finishes the system might (and will) delete it. So you are responsible for copying/moving your item to a regular folder before returning the url. Don't return the url from a tmp location. You wont find the file there anymore

Comment: So how can I store this video file somewhere to then retrieve later? It is a PHAsset, coming from users cam roll, as such it seems to go away unless saved. @LeoDabus

Comment: You have many options it all depends if you want your file to be accessible to the user or not https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: @LeoDabus "depends if you want your file to be accessible to the user or not" No. I will upload the video to firebase

Comment: You can use app support directory https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701970/2303865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't seem to want your file to be visible to users or persisted between app launches, the **`Temporary directory`** sounds perfectly fine for your use case:

```
var tempVideoFileUrl: URL {
    return FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("my_video_name")
}

func storeVideoToTemporaryFolder(videoData: Data) {
    guard !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempVideoFileUrl.path) else {
        return
    }
    do {
        try videoData.write(to: tempVideoFileUrl)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}

func loadVideoFromTemporaryFolder() -> Data? {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: tempVideoFileUrl) {
        return data
    }
    return nil
}
```

Worth mentioning though, the system may (and most likely will) purge this directory after the app is exited. It's recommended that you remove any temporary directories/files after they're no longer needed.

So in your case, you can simply remove it once you finished uploading to Firebase Storage:

```
func deleteVideoFromTemporaryFolder() {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: videoFileUrl)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

If you prefer to keep your file around between app launches though, you could use **`Application Support directory`**. But since Application Support and Documents directories gets automatically backed up, you may want to exclude your file from iCloud backup by setting its URL's `isExcludedFromBackupKey` key:

```
var applicationSupportVideoFileUrl: URL {
    let applicationSupportFolderUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    return applicationSupportFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("my_video_name")
}

func excludeFromCloudBackup(url: URL) {
    var targetUrl = url
    var isAlreadyExcludedFromBackup: Bool
    do {
        let storedRessourceValues = try targetUrl.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isExcludedFromBackupKey])
        isAlreadyExcludedFromBackup = storedRessourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup ?? false
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    guard !isAlreadyExcludedFromBackup else {
        return
    }
    var ressourceValues = URLResourceValues()
    ressourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
    do {
        try targetUrl.setResourceValues(ressourceValues)
    }
    catch {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** To get the data from your PHAsset, this should work:

```
import Photos

func loadVideoData(phAsset: PHAsset, completion: @escaping (Data?)->()) {
    guard phAsset.mediaType == .video else {
        return completion(nil)
    }
    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: options) { (avAsset, _, _) in
        guard let avUrlAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset else {
            return
        }
        var videoData: Data?
        do {
            videoData = try Data(contentsOf: avUrlAsset.url)
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(videoData)
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply call this method and store your video in the Temporary folder:

```
loadVideoData(phAsset: yourPhAsset) { [weak self] videoData in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    guard let videoData = videoData else {
        return
    }
    strongSelf.storeVideoToTemporaryFolder(videoData: videoData)
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it still does not work: 

                                    let data = NSData(contentsOf: finalURL!)
                                    let newData = Data(referencing: data!)
                                    self.storeVideoToTemporaryFolder(videoData: newData)
                                    newUserTakenVideo.videoURL = self.tempVideoFileUrl

Comment: Can you please give me more details about what exactly doesn't work? The code that I posted to read/write from/to the temporary folder is working just fine, so there must be a different problem in your code, let's find out what it is!

Comment: Also, instead of using NSData, simply use Data(contentsOf: yourUrl)

Comment: Well I run the code I just sent you right bellow let finalURL = self in PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset code you can find in my Q above. I then run, pick a video then press next , where the video is supposed to play in a view. Instead however there is a crash claiming the video URL is nil

Comment: I just edited my answer to show you a working example on how you would get the data from the PHAsset, then store it in the Temp folder, let me know how it goes :)